# Requested address is not valid in its context - Binding IP to Socket - Network Sniffing

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, ip

So I have managed to retrieve all the IP addresses on my current network. Now I am trying to capture all address that are connecting from each of my networks ip's (Which sites/addresses they visit).

For several of the IP's in my network I am returning this error "Requested address is not valid in its context", but it seems to work fine for my address only.

Currently it is only displaying the sites/addresses I am connecting to on **MY** PC and not the others.

***GOAL***: *To echo out all addresses that are requested by any of the connected IP's on my network.*

**Ex:
 
From [192.168.0.3] To => [52.321.132.2]

From [192.168.0.9] To => [79.21.23.2]**

Below is the code I am using, any help would be appreciated!

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
  class Program
   {
    static CountdownEvent countdown;
    static int upCount = 0;
    static object lockObj = new object();
    const bool resolveNames = true;
    static List<string> ADDRESSES = new List<string>();


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        #region P_1
        countdown = new CountdownEvent(1);
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        string ipBase = "192.168.0.";
        for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
        {
            string ip = ipBase + i.ToString();

            Ping p = new Ping();
            p.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(p_PingCompleted);
            countdown.AddCount();
            p.SendAsync(ip, 100, ip);
        }
        countdown.Signal();
        countdown.Wait();
        sw.Stop();
        TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(sw.ElapsedTicks);
        Console.WriteLine("Took {0} milliseconds. {1} hosts active.", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, upCount);
        #endregion

        foreach (String ip in ADDRESSES)
        {
            IPAddress y = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
            try
            {
                Sniff(y);
            }
            catch (Exception i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error for " + y + i.Message);
            }
        }
        Console.Read();

    }

    static void p_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string ip = (string)e.UserState;
        if (e.Reply != null && e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            if (resolveNames)
            {
                string name;
                try
                {
                    IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip);
                    name = hostEntry.HostName;
                }
                catch (SocketException ex)
                {
                    name = "?";
                }
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}) is up: ({2} ms)", ip, name, e.Reply.RoundtripTime);
                ADDRESSES.Add(ip);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is up: ({1} ms)", ip, e.Reply.RoundtripTime);
            }
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                upCount++;
            }
        }
        else if (e.Reply == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pinging {0} failed. (Null Reply object?)", ip);
        }
        countdown.Signal();
    }

    static void Sniff(IPAddress ip)
    {

        Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
        sck.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ip, 0));
        sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, true);
        sck.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, null);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[24];
        Action<IAsyncResult> OnReceive = null;
        OnReceive = (ar) =>
        {
            string x = new IPAddress(BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 16)).ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("From [" + ip + "] To => " + x, sck.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 24, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null)); 
        };
        sck.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
    }

   }
 }
```

Comment: "_So I have managed to retrieve all the IP's in my current network._" There are only two possible IPs: IPv4 or IPv6. I think you mean IP addresses.

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Comment: @RonMaupin I have edited the post.